# Django Migration Doesn't Work

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

i'm trying to make migrations for my app. It is not the first time that I have migrated and have always worked. But this time it seems they have worked and instead the database is not updated.

These are my models:

```
class Bambino(models.Model):
     nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     cognome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     data_nascita = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
     sesso = models.CharField(max_length=1)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.nome + ' ' + self.cognome + ' ' + self.sesso 

class Gioco(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome    

class Terapia(models.Model):
     id_bambino = models.ForeignKey(Bambino, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default='1')
     id_gioco = models.ForeignKey(Gioco, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default='1')
     nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     data_inizio = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
     data_fine = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.nome
```

Then i run the following commands:
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations (and create the file 0001_initial.py)
python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 (here shows changes in database and then COMMIT)
python manage.py migrate (this time nothing is happening)

If I check the database this is not updated.

This is the code into my 0001_initial.py

```
from _future_ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Bambino',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('nome', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('cognome', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('data_nascita', models.DateField()),
                ('sesso', models.CharField(max_length=1)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Gioco',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('nome', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Terapia',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('nome', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('data_inizio', models.DateField()),
                ('data_fine', models.DateField()),
                ('id_bambino', models.ForeignKey(default='1', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='personal.Bambino')),
                ('id_gioco', models.ForeignKey(default='1', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='personal.Gioco')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: try `python manage.py migrate app_name zero` then run `python manage.py migrate app_name`

Comment: can you check your database and see if there is `app_lable`, `0001_initial.py` in your `django_migrations` table